# Open mail database in new tab from XPiNC database

Tags: xpages

I am running an Xpage database in XPiNC and I want to have a link that will open a mail database (any arbitrary database really) in a new tab.

The code below works, IF the database is already on the workspace. If it his not, then I get the very informative message:

"Connection denied. The server you connected to has a different name from the one requested."

I really want to make sure that this db will open even if it is not on the workspace.

```
<xe:basicLeafNode label="CompuWeigh Email">
<xe:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:var url = "notes://KC1@Scoular/mail/cwmonitor.nsf?OpenDatabase?";
url}]]></xe:this.href>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Comment: What does the @Scoular do in that link? The servername in an url does not need a domain...

Comment: Well I guess it serves to screw things up. :). I took it out and it works regardless of whether or not the bookmark is on the page or not. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment: Take the domain name (`@Scoular` in the example) out of your link. then it will work

Comment: OK thanks again Have marked your solution as correct.